# Not able to exit from the powershell console after script execution

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio-code, directory

I am trying to create a script for my class to automatically create a folder monthDay wise and open it in Visual Studio Code. However, after the script executes the powershell console remains open until I close it manually or I close VSCode. I just want the console to go away after it executes. Here is the script: Please tell me how to do it..

```
# Hash table for months 
$hash_month = @{1="jan";2="feb";3="mar";4="apr";5="may";6="june";7="july";8="aug";9="sep";10="oct";11="nov";12="dec"}

#extracting date
$date = (Get-Date).Day

#extracing month
$month = (Get-Date).Month

# getting month name from the hash table
$month_name= $hash_month[$month]

# Creating the Directory with monthDate 
# This command will create a dir if it does not exist, or it will simply not execute if the directory exists
[System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory("$month_name$date")

# changing dir
cd $month_name$date

# opening the dir in vscode
code .

# currently not able to exit from console after execution of script
exit 0
```

I have attached the screenshot of the window, I just want the console to go away but **NOT** vscode.

[Powershell and VSCode Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfJri.png)

Comment: It seems that `code` is unexpectedly _blocking_ for you. You could try to work around that with `Start-Process code .`, but the bigger question is why `code` (which should resolve to `code.cmd` on Windows - try `Get-Command code) is acting this way in your case.

Comment: I tried doing `Start-Process code  .` it just opens up cmd and it remains there until I close vscode or I manually close the cmd.

Comment: That's to be expected: it is consistent with the unexpected blocking behavior of your `code` command. You can hide the  unwanted console window by adding `-WindowStyle Hidden` to the `Start-Process` call, but, again, the more interesting question why `code` behaves this way on your machine, and `Get-Command code` should help with investigating that.

Comment: `Get-Command code` is returning this,


CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     code.cmd                                           0.0.0.0    C:\Users\Ka…

Comment: That is normal so far (`code.cmd`). Solving this mystery would take more than is possible to investigate in comments here, but the `Start-Process -WindowStyle code  .` should be a viable workaround. In my experience (Windows 10 20H2, Visual Studio Code 1.57.1), `code.cmd` never blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I made 2 changes here:

1. The path creation is handled differently, which has nothing to do with the question, but your way was not creating the path for me.
2. Used Start-Process with hidden window to instantiate VSCode and make the `$pid` kill method work.

Full script:

```
# Hash table for months 
$hash_month = @{1 = "jan"; 2 = "feb"; 3 = "mar"; 4 = "apr"; 5 = "may"; 6 = "june"; 7 = "july"; 8 = "aug"; 9 = "sep"; 10 = "oct"; 11 = "nov"; 12 = "dec" }

#extracting date
$date = (Get-Date).Day

#extracing month
$month = (Get-Date).Month

# getting month name from the hash table
$month_name = $hash_month[$month]

# Creating the Directory with monthDate 
# This command will create a dir if it does not exist, or it will simply not execute if the directory exists
$path = $month_name + $date
if (!(Test-Path $path)) {
    New-Item $path -ItemType Directory
}

# # changing dir
cd $path

# # opening the dir in vscode with Start-Process
Start-Process -FilePath "code" -ArgumentList "." -WindowStyle Hidden

# # currently not able to exit from console after execution of script
Stop-Process $pid
```

Comment: I have tried doing this too, it's not working.

Comment: I was able to duplicate what you were seeing, edited the answer.

Comment: You sir, are my hero. Thankyou so much. Was struggling with it  lot.

Comment: It would be good to understand under what circumstances the VS Code CLI, `code.cmd`, unexpectedly _blocks_ on invocation (it shouldn't). Given the `Start-Process` workaround, I would expect `Stop-Process` to be unnecessary (the original `exit` should work) - or are you saying it is still necessary in order for the script to terminate?